# Switch() function not working for certain assigned measures

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am using a switch function to display data in a certain order and tag certain values to measures.  however, the result does not display the first and last category.  Here is the DAX

Report Value =

```
    IF (AND (MAX ( Main[Is sum])=2,[Filtered]),
    BLANK (), SWITCH(MIN(Main[Is sum]),
       1, [OpeningBalance],
       2, (CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Debit/Credit Amount])),
       3,(CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Debit/Credit Amount])),
       4,[ClosingBalance]
     ))`
```

---

Filtered = ISFILTERED(Submapping[Sub_grouping])
I get the result as =

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxiRi.png)

Opening balance and Closing balance are showing as blanks.  Each category is defined in the Main table and mapped to same numbers in "Is Sum" column in the Main Table.  The total appearing as row subtotal is on.

further,
relationship of tables is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uehJ6.png)
and Main table has the following data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBpV2.png)

The visual build with filters screenshot is here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8oKv.png)

Need to understand why Switch shows "Blank" values for opening and closing balance, is it due to the data filter with receipts and payments type.

the closing balance and opening balance measures are working fine when used in a table independently, but values are not reflecting within the switch command.  Also, tried using a static value for opening balance measure and it works.
Tried using ALL function in the measure for both opening and closing, but that does not seem to display the required result.

```
Opening balance = VAR PreviousClosingDate = 
IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Date 
Master'[EnglishMonthName]) < Date(2025,01,31), 
PREVIOUSMONTH('Date Master'[EnglishMonthName]),BLANK())
Var Result =
CALCULATE (SUM(Data[Debit/Credit Amount]), FILTER(ALL('Date 
Master'),'Date Master'[EnglishMonthName] <= 
PreviousClosingDate))
Return Result
```

Comment: For debugging purpose, you could replace the measures in question with a fixed value for the SWITCH statement to pick/show.

Comment: I did a static value and it works and displays the number

Comment: You could also play with the filter in your measure. set to ALL, etc.

Comment: Tried that as well, does not work, i have included the measure dax in the question.

Comment: Do you get the same result for any chosen date when you just apply the ALL() without any other filter condition in [Opening balance]? And which data type is 'Date Master'[EnglishMonthName]?

Comment: When i just apply all, the opening balance is same for all the 'Date Master'[EnglishMonthName].   And 'Date Master'[EnglishMonthName] is of Date type.  It is the last date of the month and from the Calendar table.

Comment: Usually, I would use a second, disconnected date table to handle similar cases. At the same time, I think, in this case, it should work with one as well. If you not have done it already, you could check whether [PreviousClosingDate] is calculated as expected, or replacing it with a fixed date in the filter condition to check the filtering. By the way, when you wrote it is not working with ALL() included as shown in your measure, what do you? Like blank or resulting value is not as expected?

Comment: All() resulted in blank value.  In anycase, I was able to solve this by adding Allselected() after the filter in calculate function above.  still trying to understand how it worked, but it did!!   thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe you know it already: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-allselected-in-dax/